# Regexp using literal vs. escaped character

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there any practical difference between a regexp using an escape character versus one using the literal character? I.e. are there any situations where matching with them will return different results?

Example in Ruby:

```
literal = Regexp.new("\t")
=> /    /
escaped = Regexp.new("\\t")
=> /\t/

# They're different...
literal == escaped
=> false

# ...but they seem to match the same:
"Hello\tWorld".match(literal)
=> #<MatchData "\t">
"Hello\tWorld".match(escaped)
=> #<MatchData "\t">
```

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Thanks for clarifying that this question should only apply to escaped CHARACTERS like \t or \n, not to escape SEQUENCES like \b or \s. Will edit to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in the case of `\t` (or `\n`).

But it won't work in most other cases (e.g., escape sequences that either don't have a 1:1 equivalent in string escapes like `\s` or where the meaning differs like `\b`), so it's generally a good idea to use the escaped versions (or construct the regex using `/.../` in the first place).